How to set credentials via terraform for fine-grained access control in aws opensearch?
I'm setting an opensearch cluster in aws and want to enable fine-grained access control. based on the docs , i see we specify that in advanced_security_options settings and set the enabled to true. I would like to set up a username and password as well, but the example shows, directly hardcoded values in the terraform code. can i set up a secret manager key value pair and then refer it here , such that i don't have to commit the actual username/password in the code ? also, i looked through the documenation ,but not sure how to enable vpc endpoints, any help would be great.
resource "aws_opensearch_domain" "example" {
  domain_name    = "ggkitty"
  engine_version = "Elasticsearch_7.1"

  cluster_config {
    instance_type = "r5.large.search"
  }

  advanced_security_options {
    enabled                        = true
    anonymous_auth_enabled         = true
    internal_user_database_enabled = true
    master_user_options {
      master_user_name     = "jhon"
      master_user_password = "doe"
    }
  }

  encrypt_at_rest {
    enabled = true
  }

  domain_endpoint_options {
    enforce_https       = true
    tls_security_policy = "Policy-Min-TLS-1-2-2019-07"
  }

  node_to_node_encryption {
    enabled = true
  }

  ebs_options {
    ebs_enabled = true
    volume_size = 10
  }
}

